# Is this database design circular?

Tags: mysql, database

I am working on a group management page with a variable number of tabs from which the admin(s) of each group on the site can choose for their page. Admins shall also be able to create group member roles, assign privileges on the tabs to those roles, and assign roles to the members. Any member can also belong to one or more groups.

I have sketched out some tables for the database to this. Here are the three of interest:

```
groups
----------------
GroupID <- PRIMARY KEY
GroupName
GroupDescription

group_member_records
--------------------
GroupMemberRecordID <- PRIMARY KEY
GroupID <- FOREIGN KEY: references groups.GroupID
GroupMemberID <-FOREIGN KEY: references group_members.GroupMemberID
GroupMemberRoleID <- FOREIGN KEY: references group_member_roles.GroupMemberRoleID

group_member_roles
-----------------------
GroupMemberRoleID <- PRIMARY KEY
GroupID <- FOREIGN KEY: references groups.GroupID
GroupMemberRoleName
// NOTE: GroupID,GroupMemberRoleName UNIQUE
```

I initially decided to just give `group_members` a `GroupMemberRoleID` foreign key, but the problem with that is that it would be possible for a member to belong to multiple groups, and have a group member role, and that group member role would be different for at least two of the groups of which that member belongs to! Thus, I moved the `GroupMemberRoleID` foreign key to `group_member_records`.

Before I finally implement that table that records all the tab privileges for the groups, I would like to know a couple of things:

1. Is there any risk of circular reference? I have seen closely related question [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598375/database-design-circular-references), but am unsure what they mean by:

> This is not a circular reference.
>
> It would be if emails would have a **strong integrity relationship** to
>   invitations and invitations an independent **strong integrity**
>   **relationship** back to emails (for example).

(my bold on what was unclear to me)

2. Is this, at all, bad design or bad practice?

Comment: No comment but a vote to close this question, within 8 minutes of me asking it? Whoever you are, you better explain yourself, right now.

Comment: Mike I don't think you have to worry about it closing.

Comment: Someone has a close vote on it to migrate it to the dba site. Perhaps they thought you would be better served over there. So I would relax about it. I will try to look at the question in a bit.

Comment: As I see it, you have 4 tables above (with `group_members` not being shown. Perhaps that is like a users or members table). I would ditch the `GroupID <- FOREIGN KEY: references groups.GroupID` as it seems redundant. `group_member_records` appears to be a junction table hooking group_members and roles.

Comment: Please show `group_members` in the same format as above. Is `group_member_records` really a group *membership* table?

Comment: Can members belong to different roles in the same group?